# Fetch HashMap instead of entity from Spring Repository using ehcache

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I am using ehcache for caching data in my spring project.

For example if you are fetching data mst_store table then currently I am using below code

```
public interface MstStateRepository extends JpaRepository<MstState, Integer> {

@Override
@Cacheable("getAllState")
List<MstState> findAll();
```

You can see that `findAll` method return `List<MstState>`

But instead of List what I need return type as Map. Means key as stateId and object in Value.

I can do this thing in service label but I need to write seperate logic for that as below

```
@Service 
class CacheService {
    @Autowired
    private MstStateRepository mstStateRepository;

    Map<Integer, MstState> cacheData = new HashMap<>();

    public List<MstState> findAllState() {
        List<MstState> mstStates = mstStateRepository.findAll();

        for (MstState mstState : mstStates) {
            cacheData.put(mstState.getStateId);
            cacheData.value(mstState);
        }
    }   
}
```

So instead of writing separate logic can we get directly  Map from repository. Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You could use Java 8 `default` methods for that which allows you to write a default implementation that *could* be overriden by jpa but won't be. You may also use the streams introduced in java 8:

```
public interface MstStateRepository extends JpaRepository<MstState, Integer> {

    @Cacheable("getAllState")
    default Map<Integer, MstState> getAllState(){
        return findAll().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                MstState::getStateId, 
                UnaryOperator.identity()
            ));
    }
}
```